# How to convert this data table into XML

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

There are two data tables which contains the information about file directory structure. I just wanted to convert this to XML which should best for fast & efficient parsing.

[image]

in table-1, client is the root directory & project is the folder Name inside the client (root directory) and there can be one or many folders inside of root directory (client).

```
e.g. D:\C1\P1\  /* here D:\ is the local disk */
     D:\C1\P2\
```

in table-2,  it tells about the files inside of concered root directory (client) & folder (project) and there can be many files inside of one folder.

```
e.g. D:\C1\P1\F1  /* F1 is the file name */
```

Following is the sample xml for Client(C1), Project (P1) & existing files (F1 & F2). please take a look and if it can define the better way please correct.

```
<root>
     <client>
          <id>C1</id>
          <project>
              <project-name>P1</project-name>
              <fileName>
                 <file>F1</file>
                 <file>F2</file>
               </fileName>
           </project>
     </client>
 </root>
```

***Note : *** I am using `jaxb to  marshall & unmarshall` the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write java classes that maps the table structures
2. Load table records into java objects
3. Use jaxb xml serializer to generate the xml file